# Finding div containing text

Tags: html, xpath

I have the following HTML and and XPath working

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h1>Text to find</h1></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

XPath:

```
.//div[div[@class[contains(.,'panel-heading')]][.//*[text()='Text to find']]]
```

The XPath expression will select the outer `<div>`.

Now if I remove the `<h1>` tag the XPath expression will no longer find the outer div. Can anyone explain me why, and what to do instead if I want to get the same result in the two cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `.//*` part returns *descendant elements* of the `<div class="panel-heading">`. When you remove the `h1` tag, the text node `'Text to find'` is no longer contained in any *descendant element* (it is direct child of the context element now), hence can't be found using expression `.//*[text()='Text to find']`.

To make it work with and without `h1` element, you can alter the predicate expression mentioned above to `.//text()[.='Text to find']` :

```
.//div[div[@class[contains(.,'panel-heading')]][.//text()[.='Text to find']]]
```

`.//text()` simply returns *descendant text nodes* from current context element.

Comment: Kudos for the fast response :)